# HP 1100dtn printer driver on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

Having upgraded from Windows XP to Windows 7 x64, I am unable to find a suitable driver for my HP Inkjet 1100dtn printer. Visiting HP site and searching Google suggests using HP 1000's drivers as an alternative. Having installed this however, I find the automated duplex no longer works and much of the useful features are absent.

Other than getting a new printer, or perhaps VM based solution, any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP [officially states](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&dlc=en&docname=c01796821&lc=en) that the drivers for the **Business Inkjet 1000** model are your only option in terms of Win7  compatible drivers, and the FAQ section clearly lists the limited functionality of the alternate driver. Without proper drivers there's nothing much you can do except buy a new model (exactly what they want), or continue using it with an older but supported OS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on these links,

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprohardware/thread/89e2516c-9912-477c-9d79-ca23e6db8bb5/

http://go4download.com/hp-deskjet-1100-drivers

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/51799-63-business-inkjet-1100-model-c8124a

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=306735&locale=en_us&taskId=135&prodSeriesId=306730&prodTypeId=18972

It may helps you....